# Some Kwin effects not working in Kde5 and kcmshell5 says : Could not find module 'kcm_kwin_effects'. See kcmshell5 --list for the full list of modules

Tags: 18.04, effects, kwin

I'm using XUbuntu 18.04 LTS 32bits along with Kwin instead of xfwm4.

The Cover Switch and the Flip Switch effects are not working.

Moreover, the "Desktop Cube Animation" and "Desktop Cube" effects are not available in the systemsettings5/Desktop Behavior/Desktop Effects setting window :

[image: systemsettings5/Desktop Behavior/Desktop Effects screenshot taken through ssh]

Here's some info. :

```
$ pgrep -a kwin 
31882 kwin --replace
$ kcmshell5 kcm_kwin_effects
Could not find module 'kcm_kwin_effects'. See kcmshell5 --list for the full list of modules.
$ echo $?
255
$ kcmshell5 --list | grep kcm_kwin_effects
$
$ dpkg -l | grep kwin
ii  kde-window-manager                                          4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               all          transitional package for kwin-x11
ii  kwin                                                        4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               all          Transitional dummy for kwin-x11
ii  kwin-addons                                                 4:5.12.9-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         additional desktop and window switchers for KWin
ii  kwin-common:i386                                            4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               i386         KDE window manager, common files
ii  kwin-data                                                   4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               all          KDE window manager data files
ii  kwin-style-breeze                                           4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         KWin Breeze Style
ii  kwin-style-qtcurve                                          1.8.14-3                                            i386         QtCurve window decoration for KWin
ii  kwin-x11                                                    4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               i386         KDE window manager, X11 version
ii  libkwin4-effect-builtins1:i386                              4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               i386         KDE window manager effect builtins library
ii  libkwineffects11:i386                                       4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               i386         KDE window manager effects library
ii  libkwinglutils11:i386                                       4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               i386         KDE window manager gl utils library
ii  libkwinxrenderutils11:i386                                  4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               i386         KDE window manager render utils library
ii  qml-module-org-kde-kwindowsystem:i386                       5.44.0-0ubuntu3                                     i386         provides integration of QML and KDE frameworks - kwindowsystem
$ dpkg -l | grep "^ii\s*kde"
ii  kde-baseapps                                                4:17.08.3+5.100ubuntu2                              i386         base applications from the official KDE release (metapackage)
ii  kde-baseapps-data                                           4:16.04.3-0ubuntu1                                  all          shared data files for the KDE base applications
ii  kde-cli-tools                                               4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         tools to use KDE services from the command line
ii  kde-cli-tools-data                                          4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 all          tools to use kioslaves from the command line
ii  kde-config-gtk-style                                        4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         KDE configuration module for GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3.x styles selection
ii  kde-config-gtk-style-preview                                4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         KDE configuration module for GTK+ 2.x and GTK+ 3.x styles selection (extras)
ii  kde-config-screenlocker                                     5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                   i386         KCM Module for kscreenlocker
ii  kde-config-sddm                                             4:5.12.7-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         KCM module for SDDM
ii  kde-config-tablet                                           2.0-2                                               i386         implements a KDE configuration GUI for the Wacom drivers
ii  kde-config-telepathy-accounts                               4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         KDE Control Module for managing Telepathy Accounts
ii  kde-config-whoopsie                                         15.10ubuntu2                                        i386         Configuration for Whoopsie
ii  kde-l10n-engb                                               4:17.08.3-0ubuntu4                                  all          en_GB (engb) localization for KDE
ii  kde-runtime                                                 4:17.08.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         runtime components from the official KDE release
ii  kde-runtime-data                                            4:17.08.3-0ubuntu1                                  all          shared data files for the KDE base runtime module
ii  kde-spectacle                                               17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                    i386         Screenshot capture utility, replaces KSnapshot
ii  kde-style-breeze                                            4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         Widget style for Qt and KDE Software
ii  kde-style-breeze-qt4                                        4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         Widget style for Qt 4 and KDE Software
ii  kde-style-oxygen                                            4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 all          transitional dummy package
ii  kde-style-oxygen-qt4                                        4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         Qt 4 decoration for the Oxygen desktop theme
ii  kde-style-oxygen-qt5                                        4:5.12.8-0ubuntu0.1                                 i386         Qt decoration for the Oxygen desktop theme
ii  kde-style-qtcurve-qt4:i386                                  1.8.18+git20160320-3d8622c-5build4                  i386         QtCurve widget style for applications based on Qt 4.x
ii  kde-style-qtcurve-qt5:i386                                  1.8.18+git20160320-3d8622c-5build4                  i386         QtCurve widget style for applications based on Qt 5.x
ii  kde-telepathy-approver                                      4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         KDED module for approving incoming conversations
ii  kde-telepathy-auth-handler                                  4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         KDE Telepathy authentication handler
ii  kde-telepathy-contact-list                                  4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         Telepathy contact list for the KDE Plasma Desktop
ii  kde-telepathy-data                                          4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  all          Shared data for all the KDE Telepathy components
ii  kde-telepathy-desktop-applets                               4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         KDE Telepathy contact plasmoid
ii  kde-telepathy-integration-module                            4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         Telepathy integration module for the KDE Workspace
ii  kde-telepathy-kaccounts                                     4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         kaccounts plugins for kde-telepathy
ii  kde-telepathy-kpeople                                       4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         kpeople plugins for kde-telepathy
ii  kde-telepathy-send-file                                     4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         KDE Telepathy dolphin/konqueror integration plugin
ii  kde-window-manager                                          4:5.12.9.1-0ubuntu0.1                               all          transitional package for kwin-x11
ii  kdeconnect                                                  1.3.3-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                              i386         connect smartphones to your KDE Plasma Workspace
ii  kded5                                                       5.44.0-0ubuntu1                                     i386         Extensible daemon for providing session services
ii  kdegraphics-thumbnailers                                    4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         graphics file format thumbnailers for KDE SC
ii  kdelibs-bin                                                 4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1                                i386         core executables for KDE Applications
ii  kdelibs5-data                                               4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1                                all          core shared data for all KDE Applications
ii  kdelibs5-plugins                                            4:4.14.38-0ubuntu3.1                                i386         core plugins for KDE Applications
ii  kdenetwork-filesharing                                      4:17.12.3-0ubuntu1                                  i386         network filesharing configuration module
ii  kdeplasma-addons-data                                       4:5.12.9-0ubuntu0.1                                 all          locale files for kdeplasma-addons
```

Comment: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that only days ago reached it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April)

Comment: fyi:  if your box is i386/32-bit, I don't know why you're using that software config; it can't be very efficient especially if you're using GTK3 apps. Your desktop is mostly GTK2 (XFCE in *bionic* was still only part-way through its GTK3 port; not reaching near the end-point until *eoan* or 19.10), yet you're using Qt5/KF5 packages?   You can't be worried about being *lean* on resources, so why are you still using an i386 / *bionic* release?